# Using jQuery to detect which submit button has been clicked

Tags: jquery, forms, click

Having the following form:

```
<form id="my_form">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="my_form_save"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save and apply" id="my_form_save_apply"/>
</form>
```

and the following jQuery code:

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clicked_button = e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.id;
    console.log(clicked_button)
});
```

I would like to know how to detect which of the two buttons were clicked.

The code above throws this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`.

Also, I found out that `e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.id` doesn't work on all browsers so I need another solution.

Answer (score 2):

What i suggest you is to change your code to use jquery to handle submit button click event. It will work on all browsers

```js
var buttonClicked = "";
$('#my_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  alert(buttonClicked);
  buttonClicked=""; 
});
$("#my_form input[type = 'submit']").click(function(e){
 buttonClicked = $(this).attr("id");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><form id="my_form">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="my_form_save"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save and apply" id="my_form_save_apply"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you already use jQuery I would suggest the following code:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'input', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var targetID = $(e.target).attr('id');
  if (targetID === 'my_form_save') {
    console.log('Save was clicked');
  } else if (targetID === 'my_form_save_apply') {
    console.log('Save and apply was clicked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my_form">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="my_form_save"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save and apply" id="my_form_save_apply"/>
</form>
```